# need to replace hyperlinks in email body template html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an email body template for sending email to a customer with shipping tracking nos and links to the tracking site.

The logic enables me to use this template for including upto 5 tracking nos and links. If in case a customer has only 2 tracking nos, the logic should delete other three fields.

html template for email body:

```
<body>
        Dear [FIRSTNAME]{LAST NAME},
    Your package was shipped via USPS using tracking # [TRACKINGNUMBER1], [TRACKINGNUMBER2], [TRACKINGNUMBER3], [TRACKINGNUMBER4], [TRACKINGNUMBER5]
    Track your package(s) : <a href="https://xUSPSx//[TRACKINGNUMBER1]">Click Here (#1)</a>,
    <a href="https://xUSPSx//[TRACKINGNUMBER2]">Click Here (#2)</a>,
    <a href="https://xUSPSx//[TRACKINGNUMBER3]">Click Here (#3)</a>,
    <a href="https://xUSPSx//[TRACKINGNUMBER4]">Click Here (#4)</a>,
    <a href="https://xUSPSx//[TRACKINGNUMBER5]">Click Here (#5)</a>
    Thank You.
</body>
```

Controller logic:

```
If(orderinfo.shipmethod=="FedEx")
{
emailtemplate=emailtemplate.replace("Your package was shipped via USPS","Your package was shipped via FedEx");
emailtemplate=emailtemplate.replace("https://xUSPSx//","https://xFEDEXx//");
}
string trackingnos[]=// receives all tracking nos
int arraylength=trackingnos.length;
for(int i=0; i<arraylength;i++)
{
emailtemplate=emailtemplate.replace("[TRACKINGNUMBER" + (i+1) + "], trackingnos[i]);
}
for(;arraylength<=5; arraylength++)
{
emailtemplate=emailtemplate.replace(", [TRACKINGNUMBER" + (i+1) + "], "");
emailtemplate=emailtemplate.replace(", Click Here (#" + arraylength + ")", "" );
}
```

the following controller logic works for replacing the tracking nos but the hyperlinks are still not replaced for blank fields.
Could you pls suggest a correction in my logic

Comment: in the second for loop you are using hard coded value of 5. Further, you have already got "arrayLength" calculated before first loop but you are overwriting that value in second loop. You should use second loop like this: `for(int i=0; i< arrayLength; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a template if you are going to replace everything? Why not construct it from scratch?

This is how I do it in my program adjusted to your case.

```
 private void SendEmail() //parameters if needed Client client, OrderInfo orderinfo
    {
        string trackingnos[] = ;// receives all tracking nos
        int arraylength = trackingnos.length;
        StringBuilder emailtemplate = new StringBuilder();
        emailtemplate.Append("<body>     Dear " + client.FIRSTNAME + " " + client.LastNAME + ", <br/>");
        emailtemplate.Append("Your package was shipped via " + orderinfo.shipmethod + "using tracking # ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
        {
            if (i != arraylength - 1)
            {
                emailtemplate.Append(trackingnos[i] + ", ");
            }
            else
            {
                emailtemplate.Append(trackingnos[i] + ", <br/>");
            }
        }
        emailtemplate.Append("Track your package(s) : <br/>");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
        {
            emailtemplate.Append("<a href=\"https://x"+orderinfo.shipmethod+"x//" + trackingnos[i] +"\">Click Here (#"+i+")</a>  <br/>");
        }
        emailtemplate.Append("Thank you. <br/> </body> ");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem eMail = OutlookApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        eMail.Subject = "Package shipped";
        eMail.To = client.Email;
        eMail.HTMLBody = emailtemplate.ToString();
        eMail.Send();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur brilliant suggestion. it worked!!